# How to find and remove a Google Recaptcha Java Script File

Tags: javascript, wordpress, recaptcha

on my Website pyrostern.de there's a Google Recaptcha V3 Script implemented somewhere in the files.

This is the Script: https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/HYx6hBAtwYatsD8qzq7tXNTk/recaptcha__en.js

How can I find the location of the script in my WordPress-installation and remove it? Sure in the source-code I can see the script but I don't know in which file it is located so that I can remove it.

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me with this.

Cheers, Maximo

Comment: use Notepad++ Find in Files and search the files for a keyword?

Comment: Well I would have to go through thousand different files. Isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a plugin that searches all plugins / files for a keyword you enter. Most CMS like WP have a couple of these available.
Untested Example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/